# Specify "Ask Each Time" as default for a parameter in Siri intent

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

When displaying an instance of `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController`, I want to let one of the shortcut's intent's parameters (of type `Decimal`) default to `Ask Each Time`.

Right now, it defaults to the `Default Value` value in the `.intentdefinition` file. (This field resets to `0` if left blank.)

Is there any way to define an intent such that when it's instantiated in a shortcut, it has a parameter that defaults to `Ask Each Time`?

Comment: could you please provide sample code what you are doing, as it's not quite clear

Comment: @sheshnath I think I wrote a better version here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460720/what-is-the-value-for-a-property-of-an-inintent-in-sirikit-that-represents-ask so I'm going to close this question.

Comment: ok, i'll have look

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value a not accept number that is not in the minimum and max.

[image: print screen]

And then also use the "resolve" function to validate and ask for the value using ".needsValues"

```
func resolveLevel(for intent: BrightnessSetIntent, with completion: @escaping (BrightnessSetLevelResolutionResult) -> Void) {
        
        guard let deviceIntent = intent.level else {
            completion(BrightnessSetLevelResolutionResult.needsValue())
            return
        }

        completion(BrightnessSetLevelResolutionResult.success(with: Int(truncating: deviceIntent)))
    }
```