# Can an INIntent property be given the value "Ask Each Time"?

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts

Let's say I've defined a custom intent, called `FooIntent`, in an `.intentdefinition` file.

It has a single parameter, `bar`, of type `Decimal`, for which:
- `User can supply value in Siri and Shortcuts app` is active.
- `Default Value` is `0`.

Its autogenerated class definition now looks like this:

```
public class FooIntent: INIntent {
    @NSManaged public var bar: NSNumber?
}
```

If I construct a `FooIntent`, set `bar` to `nil`, and pass it into a `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController`:

```
let intent = FooIntent()
intent.bar = nil
intent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Do foo"

let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: intent)

let viewController = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut!)
viewController.delegate = self
window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

the `Add to Siri` modal appears with the `bar` parameter filled in with `0`, its default value.

If, in the `Add to Siri` UI, I then change `bar` to `Ask Each Time` and press `Add to Siri`, the resulting delegate method call produces an `INVoiceShortcut` object that contains a `nil` value for `bar`:

```
func addVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, didFinishWith shortcut: INVoiceShortcut?, error: Error?) {
    if let intent = shortcut?.shortcut.intent as? FooIntent {
        print(intent.bar) // nil
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The same is true if I set `bar` to `Clipboard` in the UI.

If I set it to a value, e.g. `42`, then `intent.bar` correctly returns `42`.

**Since `nil` seems to represent multiple concepts for a parameter, where is the concept of `Ask Each Time` stored in the shortcut or intent objects?**

**Is there anything I can pass into `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController` such that `intent.bar = <Ask Each Time>`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you control the behavior (of whether or not to continue asking for user input for a particular param) in your **IntentHanlder**. For example I achieved to do it this way:

```
FooIntentHandler: NSObject, FooIntentHandling {

    func resolveBar(for intent: FooIntent, with completion: @escaping (FooBarResolutionResult) -> Void) {
        if let bar = intent.bar as? NSNumber {

            var everythingIsFine = false

            // Any logic here.
            // You can even assign an invalid magic number in your INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController
            // so that your compare it here to see if the user has input anything different.

            if everythingIsFine {
                completion(FooBarResolutionResult.success(with: bar))
            } else {
                // With .needsValue() Siri will always ask for user input.
                completion(FooBarResolutionResult.needsValue())
            }
        } else {
            completion(FooBarResolutionResult.needsValue())
        }
    }
}
```

You can also assign a valid value as the initial one, in which case Siri will accept the param value (without asking for user input) as long as you call `FooBarResolutionResult.success()` in your resolve method as shown above.

In short, Siri calls this `resolveBar()` to decide whether or not asking for user input.

Comment: I corresponded with an engineer at Apple about this, and he suggested that this solution is the intended one.